# Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module in my angular 11 app

Tags: angular

In my angular 11 apps, I am trying to install ngx-echats. Unfortunately, I am getting an error when exporting `NgxEchartsModule` in my `app.module.ts`.

That is the error that I am getting:

```
Error: ./node_modules/ngx-echarts/fesm2015/ngx-echarts.mjs 520:24-45
Can't import the named export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

In my app root folder, I already have an `webpack.config.js` file and it includes with :

```
module.exports = {
    configureWebpack: {
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: /\.mjs$/,
                include: /node_modules/,
                type: "javascript/auto"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Still, I am having this error. Can someone please tell me how to solve this issue?

Comment: check the version of angular cli and ngx-echarts library. it will solve your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using the latest version of ngx-echarts, version 8, which was not compatible with angular 11. Downgraded to ngx-echats, version 6 solved the issue.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You must update the angular cli to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

If you check the ngx-graph [commit history](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-graph/commits/master/?after=bb35ab559e029cefe9bbab13fa3f7af3592bee34%2069), version 8 is already for Angular 12 - you have to use the `8.0.0-rc.1` for it to work with Angular 11.